# Random three dots following UIImage in button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimage

I am trying to overlay a play image on a chat cell (UICollectionView Cell)

This is the button I am using:[image: playButton]

However, I notice this effect with every image I use. Below is the code for the button I am constructing.

```
let playButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Play Video", for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let image = UIImage(named: "play")
    button.tintColor = UIColor.white
    button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    return button
}()
```

This is what it looks like in the simulator:

[image: Screenshot from the simulator]

Why might my UIImage append these dots?

Comment: Remove setTitle for UIButton, as you don't need to show text for Play Image.

Comment: it is title of button , remove this line of code  `button.setTitle("Play Video", for: .normal)` from `playButton`  @Ricky Avina

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out :

```
let playButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let image = UIImage(named: "play")
    button.tintColor = UIColor.white
    button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    return button
}()
```

As you setting the title the title text is not fitting into the button Frame and hence you see the three dotted lines.